# I am getting this error while implementing cuberto liquid swipe animation -Could not GET 'https://maven.pkg.github.com/Cuberto/liquid-swipe-android/

Tags: java, android

I was implementing the cuberto liquid swipe animation in my app and after adding the github.properties and the dependencies as I added the code to build.gradle inside the app module that will be using the library. Then compile and run the app, it was giving an error - Could not GET 'https://maven.pkg.github.com/Cuberto/liquid-swipe-android/com/cuberto/liquid-swipe/1.0.0/liquid-swipe-1.0.0.aar'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project ..

here is my build.gradel code -

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        def githubProperties = new Properties()
        githubProperties.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("github.properties")))
        repositories {
            maven {
                name = "GitHubPackages"

                url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/Cuberto/liquid-swipe-android")
                credentials {
                    /** Create github.properties in root project folder file with
                     ** gpr.usr=GITHUB_USER_ID & gpr.key=PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN
                     ** Or set env variable GPR_USER & GPR_API_KEY if not adding a properties file**/
                    username = githubProperties['gpr.usr'] ?: System.getenv("GPR_USER")
                    password = githubProperties['gpr.key'] ?: System.getenv("GPR_API_KEY")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

 task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

here is the ss of the actual code given in the github.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQhiz.png)

and this the link to the github page of cuberto  - https://github.com/Cuberto/liquid-swipe-android

Please help me I am unable to solve this past 3 days

Comment: The GitHub repository that you mentioned has many problems. Let me fix those and notify you.

Comment: please do ..and let me know ..thanks

Comment: Hey ! Mate any improvement?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks for waiting. I have modified some Gradle files for easy importing in which you no need to generate tokens etc. [Here](https://github.com/Udhayarajan/liquid-swipe-android) is my forked and modified library. Any clarification feel free to comment and contact me.

Update based on your comment,

**Step 1:**

Make sure you have removed following code from root build.gradle,

```
def githubProperties = new Properties()
githubProperties.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("github.properties")))
repositories {
    maven {
        name = "GitHubPackages"

        url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/Cuberto/liquid-swipe-android")
        credentials {
            /** Create github.properties in root project folder file with
             ** gpr.usr=GITHUB_USER_ID & gpr.key=PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN
             ** Or set env variable GPR_USER & GPR_API_KEY if not adding a properties file**/
            username = githubProperties['gpr.usr'] ?: System.getenv("GPR_USER")
            password = githubProperties['gpr.key'] ?: System.getenv("GPR_API_KEY")
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**

In Android Studio->File->Invalidate Caches/Restart...->Invalidate and Restart(From popup dialouge)

Comment: thanks but it says dublicate dependencies of yours and the cuberto dependence but i dont have any dublicate dependency here is my build.gradel file  - 
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.core:core:1.5.0"
    implementation 'com.github.Udhayarajan:liquid-swipe-android:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.core:core:1.5.0"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"






}

Comment: @RajveerJhalani kindly check my updated answer

Comment: HEY ..i tried this but still need some help ..i am devoloping my app in java so i should still add the these depencies - implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.0-RC2' 
   implementation'androidx.core:core:1.3.1'      implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1' ???